# Encode jquery dictionary into html

Tags: jquery, html, dictionary

I have jQuery code for a dictionary translator that includes special characters and want to output the translated text on the page.

```
    var jovDict = {..., Him: '&Zcaron;&euml;b', Me: 'Do&zcaron;', 
        And: '&Scaron;efu', ...}
    var user_text = $.trim($('#eng_text').val().toUpperCase());
    var split_text = user_text.split(' ');
    var solutionVar = '';

    $.each(split_text, function (i, split_val) {
        $.each(dict, function (dict_key, dict_val) {
             if (split_val == dict_key)
                 solutionVar += dict_val + ' ';
        }
    }
    var solution = $.trim(solutionVar);

    $('#div').children('p').html(solution);
    $('#div').children('p').text(function(_, txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    });
```

Whenever I try to enter in 'Me And Him' it prints out

```
'Do&zcaron; &Scaron;efu &Zcaron;&euml;b'
```

instead of 'Dož Šefu Žëb'.

Is there a way that I can make the HTML encode the characters instead of printing it literally?

Comment: Have you set a proper character encoding? Such as `<meta charset="utf-8">`?

Comment: And both of your `$.each()` functions are missing an ending parenthesis. Should be `$.each(object, function() { //... })`

Comment: Use `html(function)` instead of `text(function)`